# KeyInfoType() got an unexpected keyword argument 'X509Data'. Signature:

Tags: python, x509certificate, zeep

Im using zeep to send a Xml but i cant sign it because i keep getting the error unexpected keyowrd argument but in docs there is clearly a x509Data

The Singature part of the request

```
'Signature': {
                                'SignedInfo': {
                                    'CanonicalizationMethod': {
                                        'Algorithm': 'http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments'
                                    },
                                    'SignatureMethod': {
                                        'Algorithm': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1'
                                    },
'Reference': {
                                        'DigestMethod': {'Algorithm': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1'},
                                        'DigestValue': 'fasf'
                                    }
                                },
                                'SignatureValue': 'xxxx',
                                'KeyInfo': {

                                    'X509Data': {
                                        'X509IssuerSerial': '',
                                        'X509SKI': '',
                                        'X509SubjectName': '',
                                        'x509Certificate': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
                                        'X509CRL': ''
                                    },


                                }
                            }
```

Here is the wsdl dump of the signature `

Global types:
xsd:anyType
ns8:UsernameToken(Username: xsd:string, Password: xsd:string)
ns7:CanonicalizationMethodType(_value_1: ANY[], Algorithm: xsd:anyURI)
ns7:CryptoBinary
ns7:DSAKeyValueType(P: ns7:CryptoBinary, Q: ns7:CryptoBinary, G: ns7:CryptoBinary, Y: ns7:CryptoBinary, J: ns7:CryptoBinary, Seed: ns7:Crypt
oBinary, PgenCounter: ns7:CryptoBinary)
ns7:DigestMethodType(_value_1: ANY[], Algorithm: xsd:anyURI)
ns7:DigestValueType
ns7:HMACOutputLengthType
ns7:KeyInfoType(({KeyName: xsd:string} | {KeyValue: ns7:KeyValueType} | {RetrievalMethod: ns7:RetrievalMethodType} | {X509Data: ns7:X509Data
Type} | {PGPData: ns7:PGPDataType} | {SPKIData: ns7:SPKIDataType} | {MgmtData: xsd:string} | {_value_1: ANY})[], Id: xsd:ID)
ns7:KeyValueType(({DSAKeyValue: ns7:DSAKeyValueType} | {RSAKeyValue: ns7:RSAKeyValueType} | {_value_1: ANY}))
ns7:ManifestType(Reference: ns7:ReferenceType[], Id: xsd:ID)
ns7:ObjectType([_value_1: ANY], Id: xsd:ID, MimeType: xsd:string, Encoding: xsd:anyURI)
ns7:PGPDataType(({PGPKeyID: xsd:base64Binary, PGPKeyPacket: xsd:base64Binary, _value_1: ANY[]} | {PGPKeyPacket: xsd:base64Binary, _value_1:
ANY[]}))
ns7:RSAKeyValueType(Modulus: ns7:CryptoBinary, Exponent: ns7:CryptoBinary)
ns7:ReferenceType(Transforms: ns7:TransformsType, DigestMethod: ns7:DigestMethodType, DigestValue: ns7:DigestValueType, Id: xsd:ID, URI: xsd
:anyURI, Type: xsd:anyURI)
ns7:RetrievalMethodType(Transforms: ns7:TransformsType, URI: xsd:anyURI, Type: xsd:anyURI)
ns7:SPKIDataType([SPKISexp: xsd:base64Binary, _value_1: ANY])
ns7:SignatureMethodType(HMACOutputLength: ns7:HMACOutputLengthType, _value_1: ANY[], Algorithm: xsd:anyURI)
ns7:SignaturePropertiesType(SignatureProperty: ns7:SignaturePropertyType[], Id: xsd:ID)
ns7:SignaturePropertyType(({_value_1: ANY})[], Target: xsd:anyURI, Id: xsd:ID)
ns7:SignatureType(SignedInfo: ns7:SignedInfoType, SignatureValue: ns7:SignatureValueType, KeyInfo: ns7:KeyInfoType, Object: ns7:ObjectType[]
, Id: xsd:ID)
ns7:SignatureValueType(xsd:base64Binary, Id: xsd:ID)
ns7:SignedInfoType(CanonicalizationMethod: ns7:CanonicalizationMethodType, SignatureMethod: ns7:SignatureMethodType, Reference: ns7:Referenc
eType[], Id: xsd:ID)
ns7:TransformType(({_value_1: ANY} | {XPath: xsd:string})[], Algorithm: xsd:anyURI)
ns7:TransformsType(Transform: ns7:TransformType[])
ns7:X509DataType([({X509IssuerSerial: ns7:X509IssuerSerialType} | {X509SKI: xsd:base64Binary} | {X509SubjectName: xsd:string} | {X509Certifi
cate: xsd:base64Binary} | {X509CRL: xsd:base64Binary} | {_value_1: ANY})])
ns7:X509IssuerSerialType(X509IssuerName: xsd:string, X509SerialNumber: xsd:integer)

Can anyone help me out thanks in advance

I really dont know what to do, i think its a zeep or lxml problem because i have a collegue that worked with this signature and the parameters are equal`